# Is it possible to put an custom indicator near the value in jsp?

Tags: jsp, displaytag

Imagine I have a array(or a table) on the website that looks like the following:

```
Item Name| Item Description | Item Register Date 
Item 2     Item Desc 2         22/05/2016
Item 5     Item Desc 5         31/03/2016
Item 4     Item Desc 4         16/02/2016
Item 1     Item Desc 1         29/11/2015
Item 3     Item Desc 3         09/08/2015
```

The table is in chronological order and the columns are sortable and here is the jsp code for the table:

```
<display:table name="testTable" class="its" uid="row"sort="list" pagesize="10" requestURI="myAction" export="false" defaultsort="3" defaultorder="descending">

<!-- 1st column -->
<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Item Name" property="itemName" 
sortable="true" />

<!-- 2nd column -->
<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Item Description" property="itemDesc" sortable="true" />

<!-- 3rd column -->
<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Item Register Date" property="itemRegDate" format="{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy}" sortable="true" />

</display:table>
```

When I run the code, the interface looks fine. However some users reflect that they want to have indicator to identify the item is the latest even the table is in chronological order. For example, they propose the interface may look like this:

```
    Item Name| Item Description | Item Register Date 
    Item 2     Item Desc 2         22/05/2016 (Latest)
    Item 5     Item Desc 5         22/05/2016 (Latest)
    Item 4     Item Desc 4         16/02/2016
    Item 1     Item Desc 1         29/11/2015
    Item 3     Item Desc 3         09/08/2015
```

So far as I know about jsp is about server side programming and use to "draw" the interface of the website. (please correct me if I am wrong)

Therefore, I am not sure if it is possible to put the indicator near the Item Register Date because in the code it retrieves the value from the database.

Due to I don't want to modify the previous code because those code written by the previous colleague, I want keep them for backup purpose.

So in the jsp file I start with a new column called "Test" and the full code of the table is look like this:

```
 <display:table name="testTable" class="its" uid="row"sort="list" pagesize="10" requestURI="myAction" export="false" defaultsort="3" defaultorder="descending">

<!-- 1st column -->
<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Item Name" property="itemName" 
sortable="true" />

<!-- 2nd column -->
<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Item Description" property="itemDesc" sortable="true" />

<!-- 3rd column -->
<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Item Register Date" property="itemRegDate" format="{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy}" sortable="true" />

<!-- 4th column for testing -->
<!-- (Latest) is the indicator for testing -->
<!-- test equal to today first-->
<s:set var="today" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>"/>

<s:out value="${today}" />
<s:if test="%{#itemRegDate==today}" /> 
<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Test" property="itemRegDate" format="{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy}" sortable="true" decorator="org.displaytag.sample.LongDateWrapper" > (Latest) </display:column>
</s:if>
<s:else>
<!--return empty in the 4th column-->
<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Test">  </display:column>
</s:else>
</display:table>
```

I run the code and get this error: HTTP Status 500 - Stream closed.

I search "java.util.stream" in the code but there is no import java.util.stream in the program.

I feel I made a mistake in the code but I am not sure in which part.

Grateful for any advice please.Thank you.

**Update**

I remove all the code in 4th column and run it, the website returns to normal.

I create an image and write the following code:

```
<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Test"><img src="<s:url value="/image/Latest.png"/>" /></display:column>
```

The result is the image does not show properly, just a cross in each row.

Then I change the code into this:

```
<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Test">        
    <s:text name="Latest"></s:text> 
</display:column>
```

This works fine, I can see each row in 4th column contains "Latest".

After that, I read this website http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-if-elseif-else-tag-example/  and apply the condition in the code.

```
<jsp:useBean id="today" class="java.util.Date" />
<s:date name="today" var="formattedDate" format="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
<s:if test="%{#itemRegDate==today}">
<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Test">        
<s:text name="Latest"></s:text> 
</display:column>
</s:if>
```

The latest result is each row contains "Latest".

I revise the code, it does not contains error and I don't understand why it does not show "Latest" in the specific row under the 4th column.

```
<s:date name="today" var="formattedDate" format="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
```

Does today is the variable? I am quite confuse about the variable.

Would someone let me know where is my mistake please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Just have an idea, is it possible that the jsp file can know the latest date and then put the indicator near that date?

Comment: I may start to write some code about this. No matter the result is success or not, I may post the code here later. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Firstly you need a property on your bean which will return true if an item is >= latest. Then in UI you can use a Decorator for that column to check the condition  to output the name and, if appropriate, an <img/> tag for the indicator. http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_decorators.html

Comment: Hello @AlanHay, thanks for your advice. I visit the website and try to put the code in the display column tag and run the code. I get an error : HTTP Status 500 - Stream closed. I guess I should take a look for the full code of the website, because at the beginning , I think it is just about the interface of the website so I only focus on the jsp file. I think I should find out where the stream located in the program to solve the error.

Comment: A quick look for the .java file that related to the table. There is no stream in the program. Perhaps I should read the content of the exception and take a search about the error.

Comment: Maybe I should post the code that cause the error to find out which part I did the mistake.

Comment: The content of the post is updated. Thank you for your kind attention.

Comment: May I ask a question please? In  `<s:if test="%{#itemRegDate==today}">`, does itemRegDate is the variable name? Does that itemRegDate equals to this itemRegDate from `<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Item Register Date" property="itemRegDate" format="{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy}" sortable="true" />` If so if I use it, I assume it contains the values that related to item register date.

Comment: If they are not equal to each other, how can I get the item register date value from `<display:column style="width: 10%" title="Item Register Date" property="itemRegDate" format="{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy}" sortable="true" /> ` because I would use that variable to apply to the if else condition for the 4th column